# Use Built-In Microphone as Input and EarPods as Output

Tags: mac, microphone, ear-phones

I am trying to record singing in Logic Pro X. I have a background track that I want the signer to be able to hear through EarPods or Beats. However, I don't want to use the microphone that comes with them; I want to use the internal microphone.

Here's System Preferences with the EarPods in:
[image]

As you can see, the only options are the microphone on the EarPods and the empty Line In port (I have an older MacBook Pro).

Without the EarPods, I get what I want:
[image]

How can I use the Internal microphone with EarPods in?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to use either `Line In` or `BoomDevice` for recording with your EarPods? That worked for me.

Comment: `Line In` is for the separate input on this Mac (Early 2011). `BoomDevice` is used by the application `Boom` to boost the output volume.